# Using the AMP cache to optimize the user experience

Tags: caching, amp-html

I have recently been reading up on the AMP-CACHE and although the URL will change in Q1 2017 the question I'm trying to understand is how to optimize the experience for a mobile user.

If you start with the view that AMP pages are the best way to show mobile users your content then if they find an AMP version of a page via Google shouldn't links take them to the AMP version of the site.

And in that case should that be the google AMP Cache version?

OR the underlying amp version that the site created.

In our case we have created an AMP version of our site

http://amp.sportsmole.co.uk

You can obviously look at and link to pages on that but the implication of some of the documentation is that using the AMP cache version is even better?

Is it and how should one do that?

When I started looking at AMP pages I wondered about this but ignored it up until now. However, the more I read about the goal of the AMP Cache the more I wonder how to take advantage of it.

Anyone have any ideas on how to use the AMP cache to make sure that the users get the fastest experience.

Answer (score 0):

You may probably want to check the [Cache optimizations and modifications](https://developers.google.com/amp/cache/overview#cache-optimizations-and-modifications) from Google documentation:

> The Google AMP Cache performs optimizations and modifications, such as the following:
>
> - Validates content is truly in AMP format, meeting all AMP performance goals.
> - Caches images and fonts in addition to AMP documents.
> - Limits maximum image dimensions to prevent browser memory issues and poor responsiveness.
> - Various transformations to improve the delivery efficiency of images via the amp-img tag, such as:
>
>   - Removal of data that is invisible or difficult to see, such as certain metadata.
>   - Conversion of images to smaller and mobile-friendlier image formats, such as converting GIF, PNG, and JPEG format images to WebP in browsers that support WebP.
>   - Transformation of the image to a lower quality if the request includes the Save-Data header.
>   - Generation of alternatively sized versions and adding srcset attributes to support delivery of responsively sized images.
> - Serves over a secure channel (HTTPS) and uses the latest web protocols (SPDY, HTTP/2).
> - Sanitizes AMP documents to prevent XSS attacks based on incorrectly closed HTML tags, comments, and more.
>
> In making the above transformations, the Google AMP Cache disregards the “Cache-Control: no-transform” header.